# Xamarin iOS: Style segue always changes back to no segue after choosing "Present Modally"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, segue

When I set the action for a segue to "Present Modally", it keeps automatically changing back to "no segue".

What should i do? :((

[image: Present Modtally]
[image: No segue]

EDIT:

This menu is on the Storyboard. When connecting one controller to another controller, Segue menu appears. After that, I want choose "Present Modally" and fill Identifier (for example--> Identifier: "showChatPrivate"), but automatically the action segue always turn into "No segue" (according to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl9yR.jpg)).

Comment: Are you using xCode or Xamarin iOS designer? I don't recognise menus from your picture

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be [Bug 44401](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44401); a fix is being worked on, but is not yet publicly available.  As a temporary workaround, please try setting the segue action by hand or use Xamarin Studio on Mac. For a notification of when the fix becomes available, you can keep an eye on the [Release Blog](https://releases.xamarin.com/). Thanks!