# Xamarin iOS Visual Studio - Can't select Show Detail Segue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm following along with the Stanford CS193P Swift/Xcode course using C# with Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio.

It's gone mostly okay despite some differences, but I am seeing weird behavior when creating segues in the designer that I can't resolve. It is hard to put into words, but basically I control-drag from a button to a view controller, select 'Show Detail' and it creates the Segue - I can see the 'S' in the circle on the Segue line. When I select the Segue, to give it an identifier, the Segue dropdown in the 'Widget' tab of the properties cycles through a few values and the ends up half height with no selected value, and the circled 'S' changes to a 'P' for popover.

A gif better demonstrates this:

[image: gif of issue]

Edit:

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a new Visual C# > iOS > Universal > Single View App project
2. Delete the default View Controller
3. Drag a Split View Controller out and delete the default View Controllers
4. Drag two View Controllers out and create master/detail relationships
5. Add a button to the master
6. Ctrl-Drag from the button to the detail and select 'Show Detail'
7. Select the newly created Segue

Comment: Why didn't you create a bug on [Xamarin's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com)? I can't see that there is much others on SO can do to help you.

Comment: @Demitrian I am not sure if it is a bug or something specific to what I have done/am using

Comment: Seems like a bug in the designer to me. I'd highly suggest that you create a bug on Xamarin's bugzilla if you didn't do so already.

Comment: Seems there is already reports of this behavior (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44401) and is fixed in the alpha channel

Comment: Good finding. Please add an answer and mark is as accepted, then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin iOS: Style segue always changes back to no segue after choosing "Present Modally"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235490/xamarin-ios-style-segue-always-changes-back-to-no-segue-after-choosing-present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Cycle9 which at the time of writing is in Alpha (per bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44401)